# Busquedas condicionados a sql desde c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]C# no me quiere leer el código me lo marca completo como error no se si es por la forma en que estoy encerrando cada caso.

los `dtpdesde` y `dtphasta` son controles `DateTimePicker`

`txtbusqueda` y `txtmodelo` son controles `TextBox`

`cbtipo` es un control `ComboBox`

```
string sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + dtpdesde.Text + "' AND '" + dtphasta.Text + "'  AND [Descripcion de Articulo]= '" + txtbusqueda.Text + "' AND Marca='" + txtmodelo.Text + "' AND [Tipo de Articulo]='" + cbtipo.SelectedItem + "'");
```

Error que me dispara:

no se puede convertir explicitamente a string datos de System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Independiente del error, por favor te insto a que leas sobre "sql injection", tu código es sumamente vulnerable a esto

Comment: gracias lo tendre en cuenta @Lamak

Comment: Como dice @Lamak es una pésima idea ejecutar esa consulta concatenando la query.

Comment: Igual no compartes el texto de tu error, ni nada, por lo que es difícil determinar cual es tu problema.

Comment: Por favor si tienen la respuesta o donde puedo encontrarla les agradeceria mucho, algun video que ver, un libro lo que sea

Comment: Ya lo edite @AgustinM.

Comment: vuelve a poner el error, lo edité antes de que tu lo hicieras jajaja.

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor la cuestión con tu inquietud es que la pregunta **no es clara**, sería más fácil ayudarte si compartes una captura del error, y nos cuentas en que entorno estas trabajando (Winforms, WPF, ASP). Todos esos datos son necesarios para poder elaborar una respuesta.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en c#, winforms @AgustinM.

Comment: Te estás olvidando de pasarle un parámetro al constructor del SqlCommand que es la conexión, que va luego de la query.

Comment: ok si tienes razon @AgustinM. ya la agrege pero quisiera que le echen un ojo a la forma en que encierro cada control osea las comillas simples y dobles... y si esta bien que para que la busqueda tome el valor de lo que este seleccionado en el momento de ejecutar la consulta pusiera cbtipo.SelectedItem

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor es que en ese caso, esta pregunta se transforma en "demasiado amplia"

Comment: bueno esta bien gracias @Lamak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le estas asignado una instancia de tipo `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` a una variable que es del tipo `System.String`

```
string sql = new SqlCommand("...");
```

Intenta esto:

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sql aqui");
```

Nota: Para que puedas protegerte de las injecciones sql te recomiendo la libreria [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). Muy rapida y facil de utilizar.

Comment: gracias ya habia llegado a esa conclusion hace unos minutos, es que soy novato y aun se me pasan cosas fundamentales

Comment: Me alegra que te haya ayudado. Suerte!

Answer (score 2):

Tienes el error a la vista:

> no se puede convertir explicitamente a string datos de
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

¿Que quiere decir esto? que estas tratando de convertir algo, en algo que no es.

En tu caso, tu código es:

```
string sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + dtpdesde.Text 
+ "' AND '" + 
 dtphasta.Text + "'  AND [Descripcion de Articulo]= '" 
+ txtbusqueda.Text + "' AND Marca='" + txtmodelo.Text + "' 
AND [Tipo de Articulo]='" + cbtipo.SelectedItem + "'");
```

y el error mismo te lo dice. SqlCommand no es un string, es un objeto SqlCommand.

Por desgracia, pusiste una imagen, y no se que trataste de hacer después, pero el error principal es que sql tiene que ser del tipo SqlCommand.